# Inheriting functions that return generic types

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I'm attempting to write two classes, call 'em Parent and Child.

parent is an abstract class that defines a function that returns a (sort of) generic type

```
public abstract class Parent
{
     public abstract KeyValuePair<K,V> foo(someInputs);
}
```

with the intention being that Child can override this function to return a KeyValuePair with different types as the key and value.

```
public abstract class Child
{
     public override KeyValuePair<string,int> foo(someInputs)
     {
          return(new KeyValuePair<string,int>(someInput1,someInput2);
     }
}
```

This achieves the goal of communicating to the user developing the child(future me) that the function needs to return a KeyValuePair, but that I am free to use whatever KeyValuePair I want.

Unfortunately though it seems the only way to achieve this is to also make the class generic,

```
public abstract class Parent<K,V>
```

and pass K and V down to the abstract function.

This means that when I am writing the child, I need to define the same types for the class (which is now generic) and function return. If they do not match, the compiler poops itself (with good reason).

Is there a way to have these "semi generic" return types without making the class generic?

Comment: It is not clear to me why making `Parent` generic is an issue for you.  Why are you trying to avoid doing that?

Comment: What would be the point of doing this? You can't have a `KeyValuePair<K,V>` outside of a generic method/class anyway. So you could never call `foo` on a `Parent` reference. So why put it in the base class at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes with different generic parameters are totally different things.

```
KeyValuePair<string, int>

KeyValuePair<string, Graphics>
```

For example, the above two KeyValuePairs are not interchangeable.

Let say, you have 2 child classes:

```
public abstract class Child1 : Parent
{
    public override KeyValuePair<string, int> foo() { ... }
}

public abstract class Child2 : Parent
{
    public override KeyValuePair<string, Graphics> foo() { ... }
}
```

Parent class has no way to satisfy both children in one declaration.

> free to use whatever KeyValuePair I want

Therefore, such freedom is not logically correct.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I realized that I was writing the whole thing wrong, and this requirement was a symptom of this bad design decision.

Answer (score 0):

You can have children implement a generic interface and a non-generic base class (if necessary)?

```
public abstract Parent
{
   // common non-generic methods
}

public interface IFooable<T>
{
    KeyValuePair<string, T> Foo();
}

public class Child1 : Parent, IFooable<int>
{
    public virtual KeyValuePair<string, int> Foo()
    {
    }
}

public class Child2 : Parent, IFooable<string>, IFooable<bool>
{
    public KeyValuePair<string, string> Foo()
    {
    }

    public KeyValuePair<string, bool> Foo()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this still requires defining the type itself twice over, and also involves making an interface now. I've since realized that the original design was faulty at its core, and my needing such an interface was a symptom.